# navigate to a component related to another module in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, router, ngroute

i use this [template](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6) and i want to navigate from login component, to another component related to other module,
i have used this.router.navigate(['myRoute']); and this.router.navigateByUrl('myRoute'); but it doesn't work

Comment: Share your app.routing.module.ts

Comment: how to do it plz @niteshbisht

Comment: Share the code of app.routing.module.ts in question

Comment: i use this template , this is the app routing file https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: which route component you want to navigate?

Comment: I am able to navigate to route to the component
use this.router.navigate(['./routename']);

Answer (score 0):

You can route to the component using

```
this.router.navigate(['./routename']);
```

To see more routing log/information in your routing module

Change to this to enable roting debug logs and add hash in path

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{enableTracing:true, useHash: true})],
```

Comment: i have used this.router.navigate(['./routename']);  but no result,  i want to navigate to a component related to anther module for example dashboard in layout module      https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6/blob/master/src/app/layout/layout-routing.module.ts

Comment: yes i was able to route to signUp route of Signup Module